# How to calculate $\int \frac{x^2 }{(x^2+1)^2} dx$?

Tags: integration

I'm trying  to calculate $\int \frac{x^2 }{(x^2+1)^2} dx$ by using the formula:
$$ \int udv = uv -\int vdu $$

I supposed that $u=x$ s.t $du=dx$, and also that $dv=\frac{x}{(x^2+1)^2}dx$, but I couldn't calculate the last integral. what is the tick here?

> > the answer must be: $ \frac{1}{2}arctan\ x - \frac{x}{2(1+x^2)} $ + C

Comment: Let $t = x^2$ to help you integrate your $dv$.

Comment: @Unit do you mean substituting $x$ in $dv$ with $\sqrt{x}$ ? isn't that complicated?

Comment: Some functions $v$ such that $dv=\frac{x}{(x^2+1)^2}dx$ are $v=-\frac12\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ and $v=+\frac12\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}$. (This merely amplifies @Unit's idea.)

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani I do not know exactly how far you are in studying this topic, but a next nice follow up question would be to find the answer when integrating from say 0 to infinity.

Comment: @Did Okay, how did you knew these functions exist? this is actually my question.

Comment: @Unit how to do it? its not working!!!

Comment: The ratio $x/(x^2+1)^2$ is, up to a multiplicative factor, $w'(x)/w(x)^2$ with $w(x)=x^2+1$. The rest follows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you used parts: with $u = x$ and $dv = \frac{x}{(x^2+1)^2}dx$, you got $$\int\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}dx = xv - \int v\,dx.\tag{1}$$
From here, I suggested the substitution $t = x^2$ in order to integrate $dv$ and get $v$. 
Doing this, we see that $dt = 2x\,dx$, so $x\,dx = \frac{1}{2}dt$.
Thus $$v = \int dv = \int \frac{x}{(x^2+1)^2}dx = \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{dt}{(t + 1)^2}.$$
This latter integral is easy: if you can't guess it, let $s = t + 1$. 
In any case, we get $$v = -\frac{1}{2(t+1)} = -\frac{1}{2(x^2+1)}.$$
Going back to $(1)$,
$$\int\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}dx = -\frac{x}{2(x^2+1)} + \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{dx}{x^2+1}$$
and you should recognize the final integral as $\arctan{x}$.
Putting it all together, the answer is 
$$\frac{1}{2}\arctan{x} - \frac{x}{2(x^2+1)} + C.$$

Comment: I wish I can thank you more than just choosing your answer as "Best Answer".

Comment: Your thankful comment is thanks enough!

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Use trigonometric substitution  $x=\tan\theta$

$\int\dfrac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}dx=\cdots=\dfrac12\int(1-\cos2\theta)d\theta$

$\sin2\theta=\dfrac{2\tan\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}$

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure that I learned this trigo equation, but It lookds like a nice idea. thats for the effort. i will be glad if u can solve it in other way, or at least, according to this formula.

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani, See http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/integration/trigsub/trigsub.html

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\dfrac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}dx$$

$$=x\int\dfrac x{(x^2+1)^2}dx-\int\left[\frac{dx}{dx}\cdot\int\dfrac x{(x^2+1)^2}dx\right]dx$$

$$=x\cdot\frac{-1}{1+x^2}+\int\dfrac{dx}{1+x^2}=\cdots$$